# EF5 , Widows Forms , Dragging a chield entity from project datasource into a GridView creates only 2 columns

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

After moved to EF5, created a diagram with 2 tables linked thru a FKey like Order/Order Details , then create a new project datasource with the Order object , dragging a column into a text box creates a binding source successfully , but then dragging the child entity OrderDetails into a gridview creates only 2 columns Count & IsReadOnly .

VS2010 or 2012 , same
.NET 4.0 or 4.5 , same problem

return to EF4 , problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been posted on the EF codelex site [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/639)