# Can I use EF4 in VS 2012?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I wanted to follow up on a post from last year (["EF5 , Widows Forms , Dragging a chield entity from project datasource into a GridView creates only 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210738/ef5-widows-forms-dragging-a-chield-entity-from-project-datasource-into-a-gri?answertab=active#tab-top)").

I believe the problem described with EF5 is still true and the solution found (use EF4) continues to be the only reasonable answer.

Before I upgrade to VS2012, I wanted to check whether anyone knows if there is any problem using EF4 in VS 2012.

Anyone with experience on this?

Comment: Using it at the moment, no issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2012 requires .NET Framework 4.5 which is an in-place update. This means that once you install the .NET Framework 4.5 it will be always used when running .NET Framework 4 or .NET Framework 4.5 apps. This also means that you will be running EF5 even if you target .NET Framework 4 in VS (targeting is only a design time thing which prevents from using APIs that were not available in the targeted .NET Framework version while at runtime the app will use the version installed on the box). 
With regards to the problem you are reporting - take a look at [this bug report](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/639) on the EF codeplex site as it apparently contains a solution to the problem

Comment: Thanks, Pawel.  I understand .NET version targeting in VS, but I'm not sure that is the whole picture that I need be concerned with.  If VS.NET 2012 by default does the EF5 "add code generation item" step in the designer (that I must do manually in VS2010), I might be stuck.  At least in 2010, I can just not do it.  Do you know if VS 2012 forces it, and/or if I will be able to control it (revert to the code generator for EF4)?

Comment: In VS2010 the default code gen strategy for EF was Single File Generator that created ObjectContext based context and EntityObject based entities. So, it was not that you did not do code generation. It was done for you by default but a bit differently. In VS2012 the default code gen strategy is T4 template based which generates POCO entities and DbContext based context. This will work on a .NET Framework 4 box as long as your app will contain reference to the correct version of EntityFramework.dll (which should be added to the project when you create a new model) (continued below...).

Comment: (continued...) If you want to go back to ObjectContext based context and EntityObject based entities and the code that was generated for you before you can change the code gen strategy from "None" to "Default" and remove the T4 templates from your project.